# php removing excess whitespace

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove excess whitespace from a string like this:

> hello        world

to

> hello world

Anyone has any idea how to do that in PHP?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With a regexp :

```
preg_replace('/( )+/', ' ', $string);
```

If you also want to remove every multi-white characters, you can use \s (\s is white characters)

```
preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: The parenthesis in your regexes are not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = 'Why   do I
          have  so much white   space?';

$str = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $str);

var_dump($str); // string(34) "Why do I have so much white space?"
```

[See it!](http://codepad.org/fu2eKR0n)

You could also use the `+` quantifier, because it always replaces it with a . However, I find `{2,}` to show your intent clearer.

Comment: Tried this but doesn't remove spaces at the beginning or at the end of the text. If the string is `$str='    Text       with       a       lot        of       spaces        ';`, it returns `' Text with a lot of spaces '`. I expect `'Text with a lot of spaces'`.

Comment: @Mai That's because the code doesn't remove spaces, it collapses them into one. If you want to trim the string, use `trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on how to strip excess whitespace in the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) documentation

Comment: The example has `\s\s+`. Why? I can understand if they used an asterisk instead of a plus. An asterisk means zero or more occurrences. Therefore, you have to double the regex. However, a plus means one or more. Is there a particular reason? It should still work, but it seems unnecessary.

Comment: W. I think the reason is to make it match on only 2 or more spaces -- if there's only one space, no need to do the replacement. This is, incidentally, equivalent to `\s{2,}` as in alex's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a PHP expert, but his sounds like a job for REGEX....

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello     World     and Everybody!';
$pattern = '/\s+/g';
$replacement = ' ';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Again, PHP is not my language, but the idea is to replace multiple whitespaces with single spaces. The `\s` stands for white space, and the `+` means one or more. The `g` on the end means to do it globally (i.e. more than once).