# How to remove successive whitespace php & sql server

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have a table in database :

```
-------------------------------------------
ID      car      Description    
-------------------------------------------
1       car1      descreption of the car1
2       car2      description of the  car2
3       car3      descreption of the car3
```

I imported the data of the table from an Excel worksheet using **import and export data** tool of SQL Server 2008.

I created a PHP application to manage this database and to do some operations with it.
My problem is :

1. for some values in the Description column, i found that there is some values with successive whitespace, there is any why to delete successive whitespace and keep only one?
2. Another question, does PHP delete successive whitespace when we use _POST ot _GET ?

NB : Because in the database i find some descriptions containing more than one whitespace  separating each word, but in my application it gives me the same row with only one whitespace between words!!

i can't understand what happened

Answer (score 0):

1. Use regular expressions to remove excessive white-space.

   ```
   preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $string);
   ```

   Reference: [php removing excess whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300440/php-removing-excess-whitespace)
2. PHP does not edit any _POST or _GET values. It keeps it exactly the way it was received.